# how to implant admob in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, admob

these are the code i am using in android studio latest release
using dependence com.google.android.gsm:google-play-service 15.0.5
app did't show ads on app.

i also tried firebase but whenever i use that after installing app in android phone app crash.
or like wouldn't open.

**mainactivity.java**

```
package com.animefantasy.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btShow;
AdView adView1,adView2;
InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
btShow = findViewById(R.id.bt_show);
adView1 = findViewById(R.id.ad_view1);
adView2 = findViewById(R.id.ad_view2);
MobileAds.initialize( this,"ca-app-pub-6273282658515300~1329562880");
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView1.loadAd(adRequest);
adView2.loadAd(adRequest);

interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-6273282658515300/7818594399");
interstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
btShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
interstitialAd.show();
}

});
}
}
```

**androidmannifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.animefantasy.myapplication">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**activity main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<Button
android:id="@+id/bt_show"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:text="Show Ad"
android:textAllCaps="false" />
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/ad_view1"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-6273282658515300/3583835917"/>
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/ad_view2"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-6273282658515300/2972875090"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you provide crash logs?

Comment: @ErenTüfekçi      Event Log    16-11-2019
20:14 Gradle sync started with single-variant sync

20:14 Project setup started

20:14 Gradle sync finished in 6 s 143 ms (from cached state)


20:14 NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.4.1, NDK version is UNKNOWN

20:16 Gradle build finished in 1 m 33 s 640 ms                                        first i build apk in android studio and then copied it in my android phone so i don't have crach log. i am using AMD rygen 3 so vt-x and svm doesn't work for me. so i cant use emulator.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** It is not recommended to use two banners in the same activity.

**2.** Add into your **AndroidManifest:**

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="your_app_id_for_ads"/>

    ...
```